# Why is loading qgs/qgz 2 x slower than loading qlr?

Tags: qgs, loading, qgz, qlr

I have a Layer Definition file(.qlr) that takes 50sec to load. When I save it as a project(qgs/qgz) it takes over 2min to load the same data. Why does loading of qgs/qgz take longer than loading qlr?
It seems like the extra time is used after all the layers are loaded(100%), so QGIS seems to be hanging for over 1min.
My data are all based on PostGIS-views, and are both point, lines and polygons. Symbology is saved in the PostGIS-db.

Comment: Does the project have any other data sources in it? Does this happen if you make a new project, just load the qlr, save and reload?

Comment: All the data sources are the same, PostGIS. Have tried loading qlr in empty QGIS, saving it as a new project,. The new project take 2 x time to load compared to the qlr file.

Comment: Could you try to measure the times and see it if is a clear 2x of time (or look server side what queries happen)? I had remotely similar issues in the past and maybe the data is loaded twice?